# How to use hibernate tools to generate POJO classes in JPA standard?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I use hibernate tools to generate POJO classes in java, I am getting annotated classes. But there are not in JPA standard.

For instance, I see annotations above the getter methods. But I need these annotations above the variable declaration.

Do you know any alternative or configurations changes to achieve JPA standard?

Answer (score 1):

*When using the  tag or the Eclipse plugin to generate POJO Java code you have the ability to control certain aspects of the code generation process. This is primarily done with the  tag in the mapping files. The following section describes the possible  tags and their use.*

Please reff :- http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#codegen